# Left Click Event in Word

Tags: c#, events, ms-word, click, vsto

I need to know if there is any possibility to create a completely new event or may I'm blind and there is one...

Exactly I have a button in my word ribbon > after a click on it the user should click anywhere in the document to create a richtextbox (the windows.forms) and for this I need the click position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a TextBox over the whole page. With this Box I created a click event and so i got the exact position. I know this isn't the best possibility but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no such event in a Word add-in. See: [Mouse Events in Word 2010 application level AddIn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/960e1ddf-9ed4-440b-b2bd-2f5d8a396b26/mouse-events-in-word-2010-application-level-addin?forum=vsto)

As mentioned in that post, the use of WinApi could be an approach.

Or maybe the ["Document.SelectionChange Event"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.selectionchange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could help with this problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I tried to do this for about 2 hours and i can't do it ... does anyone know a good example for my problem? I need it for my school project and I haven't the time to learn WinApi as fast as i need it.

And I also tried it with the selectionchange event but thats not what i'm looking for ...