# Change a font color of bookmarked range by clicking it

Tags: vba, ms-word, com-automation

I have Word document with sections and bookmarked ranges. I would like to format range by clicking it (Change font color between black and red). Is that possible with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font color in Word in the following way:

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
```

To change the font color of selected text in Word you can use the following code:

```
Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
```

You may find the [VBA Word: Difference between Font.TextColor and Font.ColorIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488755/vba-word-difference-between-font-textcolor-and-font-colorindex) page helpful.

To detect mouse clicks in a document you'll have to use WinAPI functions. The Word object model doesn't provide anything for that. Read more about that on the [Left Click Event in Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589732/left-click-event-in-word) thread.